# Orienting a three.js material based on camera position, with rotated mesh

Tags: three.js, webgl

I have a question about orienting a threejs material (custom fragment shader) toward the camera, on a mesh that has been rotated.

The effect I'm looking for is a sphere that appears transparent in the center and gets progressively more opaque towards the edges.  I got that working based on [this demo](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Shader-Glow.html).  Problem is, the technique fails if the mesh is rotated.

Here's a live demo of the problem: http://palebluepixel.org/demos/threejs-rotation-question/

The spheres are identical, but one of them is rotated every frame (`earthBad.rotation.y += 0.005;`).  By rotating it, the transparent half of the sphere rotates with it.

**vertex shader**

Calculate `intensity` of transparency based on the angle between normal vector and view vector.

```
uniform vec3 spherePosition;
uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
varying float intensity;
varying vec2 vUv;
void main() 
{
    vec3 viewVector = cameraPosition - spherePosition;
    vec3 vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal );
    vec3 vNormel = normalize( normalMatrix * viewVector );
    intensity = pow( 1.0 - dot(vNormal, vNormel), 0.5 );
    vUv = uv;

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
}
```

**fragment shader**

Use texture map and override alpha channel with the `intensity` value.

```
uniform sampler2D sphereTexture;
varying float intensity;
varying vec2 vUv;
void main()
{

    vec4 fragColor = texture2D(sphereTexture, vUv);
    fragColor.a = intensity;
    gl_FragColor = fragColor;
}
```

When the mesh isn't rotated, the transparent half of the sphere follows the camera perfectly.  However when the mesh is rotated, the transparent half rotates with it.

[image: image of rotated mesh looking wrong]

To my amateur eyes, it seems like three.js applies rotation to the mesh after the material's shaders have run.

How can I solve this?  I tried pulling the mesh's `quaternion` into the shader, thinking I could apply reverse rotation to the `intensity` calculation, but the math eluded me.